# Unable to use mount -rw

Tags: grub2, mount, password, root, recovery-mode

I forgot my password to the root account, I have autologin enabled so I can use it, but unable to make changes in it. After searching and searching I found a "solution" which does not work for me at all.

I open "Advanced settings for Ubuntu" and choosed Ubuntu with Linux generic 3.8 (recovery mode), choosed root, and entered

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

but it doesn't work, it shows "help" about mount (`mount --make ; -o [options] [passwdfd]` and so on), but not what it was supposed to do. Tried again and again but still nothing. I get the manipulation token error if I try to ignore the mount stuff.

Has anyone any advice or suggestions on how to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

`rw` isn't another flag, it's another option.

Answer (score 0):

To re-set the root password see this: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Then to re-set the user password you have to get to start Terminal and type in `su` enter the admin password then type `passwd <USER>` to recreate a password replacing  with your username.